# discord.py - How to I pin a slash command response with a button?

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm having an issue with trying to pin a slash command response. I've tried `await interaction.response.pin()` and that didn't work. It just gave me the error `AttributeError: 'InteractionResponse' object has no attribute 'pin'`. Does anyone know how to pin one?

(this is a response for a **button,** once you press a button, it pins the response)

edit:

```
class suggestion_options(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, embed):
        super().__init__()
        self.embed = embed

    @discord.ui.button(label='Deny Suggestion', emoji="❌", style=discord.ButtonStyle.primary)
    async def asdf(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
        view = undor(undor)
        await interaction.response.edit_message(content=f"Status: Denied", view=view)

    @discord.ui.button(label='Accept Suggestion', emoji="✅", style=discord.ButtonStyle.primary)
    async def hjkl(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
        view = undor(undor)
        await interaction.response.edit_message(content=f"Status: Accepted", view=view)
        
    @discord.ui.button(label='Save for Later', emoji="⏱️", style=discord.ButtonStyle.secondary)
    async def qqeqe(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
        print("e")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class View(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, embed):
        super().__init__()
        self.embed = embed

    @discord.ui.button(label='Confirm', style=discord.ButtonStyle.green)
    async def asdf(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
        await interaction.response.edit_message(content="Your suggestion has been sent successfully.", embed=None, view=None)
        channel = interaction.guild.get_channel(log_channel_id)
        message = await channel.send(embed=self.embed)
        await message.pin()
```

You need to make a message variable then use the `pin()` function to get the message pinned.

Comment: thats for the confirm I have a button to save it later, and I want it to pin that (check edits)

Comment: Okay. You can do the same thing whit it. Get the message variable and pin it. Check my other answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Pin(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self,message_to_pin):
        super().__init__()
        self.message_to_pin = message_to_pin
    @discord.ui.button(label="Pin It", style=discord.ButtonStyle.green)
    async def pinit(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
        if self.message_to_pin:
            channel = interaction.guild.get_channel(log_channel_id)
            message = await channel.fetch_message(self.message_to_pin)
            await message.pin()

class View(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, embed):
        super().__init__()
        self.embed = embed


    @discord.ui.button(label='Confirm', style=discord.ButtonStyle.green)
    async def asdf(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
        await interaction.response.edit_message(content="Your suggestion has been sent successfully.", embed=None, view=None)
        channel = interaction.guild.get_channel(log_channel_id)
        message = await channel.send(embed=self.embed)
        message_to_pin = message.id
        view = Pin(message_to_pin)
        await message.edit(embed=self.embed, view=view)
```